# There is an issue on connecting to the DB in HUE

Tags: python, hue

Issue in DB connection setup on HUE tool, the exception error message I get as Connection Failed: Error accessing the database: invalid syntax (rdbms.py, line 46)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKapx.png)

Actually, I tried installing the HUE in docker with the image gethue/hue:latest with the run command provided in the docker hub docker run -it -p 8888:8888 gethue/hue:latest container created URL got loaded the I tried to connect the database but its refusing with above mentioned error.